# Is the C# compiler unable to infer method type parameters by expected return type?

Tags: c#, type-inference

This seems odd to me, but I remember a thread where Eric Lippert commented on the inability (by design, or at least convention, I think) of C# to overload methods based on return type, so perhaps it's in some convoluted way related to that.

Is there any reason this does not work:

```
public static T Test<T>() where T : new()
{
    return new T();
}

// Elsewhere
SomeObject myObj = Test();
```

But this does:

```
 var myObj = Test<SomeObject>();
```

From a certain perspective, they're both fine, in that you're not Repeating Yourself (in a very small way), but is this just a different pass of the compiler?

Comment: Covariance/contravariance? I think you probably have to state the version of C# you are refering to. http://bit.ly/gG4Iis Edit: I'm wrong here; C++ cannot overload based on return type, too. After all, the return type can be completeley omitted, so I see no reliable way for the compiler to detect the correct function.

Comment: I'm assuming in bringing up covariance/contravariance that you're addressing return type resolution; as I figured, that was pretty much a red herring, but still a worthwhile point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check C# Language Specification §7.5.2, the declaring type of a variable is not an attestation for type inference, and obviously it shouldn't be. Consider the following code:

```
Base b = Test<Derived>();
Derived d = Test<Derived>();
```

The return type of the method probably differs from the declaring type of the variable, since we have implicit convert in C#.

Comment: Gets the check, if only for citing the relevant spec section :)

Comment: “and obviously it shouldn’t be” – why the heck not? Java allows this when it’s not ambiguous, and I think this is one of the very few cases where Java got it right and C# got it wrong.

Comment: @Konrad Rudolph: Java got it right and C# got it wrong? Prove it. In my unreleased(and never will be released) personal programming language, 1+1=3, so can I say it's correct while Java/C# is wrong because they have 1+1=2? Here I'm talking about things in C#.

Comment: The "right" choice is of course a matter of opinion. All design choices in C# are the result of careful consideration of many competing alternatives. In my opinion, this choice is more consistent with the underlying design principles of C# than the alternative. Whether the inventors of Java had different design principles, I don't know; you'd have to ask them why they made different choices.

Comment: Smartest: well, when I said that Java did it right I obviously meant that Java’s design decision is better than C#’s. What’s there to prove? The code works and this is helpful, though not crucial. Obviously people disagree (e.g. Eric) but for the record, I’m utterly unmoved by his explanation. It’s a good *technical* explanation but it leaves the user experience out and in my opinion, that’s what language design must cater to. What’s more, there’s precedence (look at Eric’s answer) so even his technical explanation doesn’t really work out.

Answer (score 5):

First off, this is "overloading based on return type":

```
void M(int x){...}
int M(int x){...}
string M(int x){...}
```

The *declarations* are not legal; you can't overload a method based on return type because the return type is not part of the signature, and the signature has to be unique.

What you are talking about is *method type inference* based on the method's return type. We don't support that either.

The reason is because *the return type might be what you are trying to figure out*.

```
M(Test());
```

What's the return type of Test?  That depends on which overload of M we choose. What overload of M do we choose? That depends on the return type of Test.

In general, C# is designed so that every subexpression has a type, and the types are worked out from the "inside" towards the "outside", not from the outside to the inside.

The notable exceptions are anonymous functions, method groups, and null:

```
M(x=>x+1)
```

What's the type of x=>x+1? It depends on which overload of M is called.

```
M(N); // N is a method group
```

what's the type of N? Again, it depends on which overload of M is called.

And so on. In these cases we do reason from "outside" to "inside".

Type inference involving lambdas is extremely complicated and was difficult to implement. We don't want to have that same complication and difficulty throughout the compiler.

Comment: Sorry, I'm definitely aware of the definitions and distinctions of the two, but re-reading, brevity makes "somehow related in terms of implementational motivation" into "these things are close to being the same." Didn't mean that. My question was [supposed to be] more about intention, rather than syntactic legality, so your last paragraph is pretty much precisely what I was aiming for. :)

Answer (score 4):

Except for typeless expressions (`null`, method groups, and lambda expressions), the type of an expression must be statically determinable by the expression itself, regardless of context.

In other words, the type of an expression `Test()` cannot depend on what you're assigning it to.

Comment: Conditional operators are typed. I think you meant to say "null literals, method groups, and anonymous functions".

Answer (score 1):

Type inference by the compiler doesn't use the "expected type" of an assignment as part of the logic.

So, the "scope of consideration" for type inference is not this:

```
SomeObject myObj = Test();
```

but this:

```
Test();
```

And, there are no clues here as to the expected type.

Answer (score 1):

If you want an example of *why* the type of an expression needs to be able to be determined by the expression itself, consider the following two cases:

1. We don't use the return value at all - we're just calling the method for its side-effects.
2. We pass the return value directly into an overloaded method

Using the "expected type" of the return value when it comes to generic type resolution would introduce a whole whack of additional complexity into the compiler, and all you've gained is that sometimes you need to explicitly specify the type and sometimes you don't, and whether you need to or not can change based on unrelated changes elsewhere in the code.